# insert plugin into Android gradle build using init.gradle

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin, fdroid

[F-Droid](https://f-droid.org) is a free software app store for Android.  We enforce that apps are 100% free software, so its something like Debian for Android.  Since most Android apps use gradle, it makes sense to use gradle tricks to [automate our enforcement](https://gitlab.com/fdroid/fdroidserver/issues/313).  The `'com.jaredsburrows.license'` plugin is one kind of thing we'd like to automatically inject into every build.  *init.gradle* should be able to do this, but I can't quite figure out how to insert the plugin into the Android plugin.  Here's where I got:

```
apply plugin: FDroidLicenseCheck

class FDroidLicenseCheck implements Plugin<Gradle> {
  def supportedPlugins = [
    'org.gradle.api.plugins.JavaPlugin',
    'com.android.build.gradle.AppPlugin'
  ]

  void apply(Gradle gradle) {
    println('applying license check')
    def added = false

    gradle.allprojects { project ->
      project.with { 
        if (parent == null) {
          buildscript { 
            repositories {
              jcenter()
            }
            dependencies {
              classpath "com.jaredsburrows:gradle-license-plugin:0.5.0"
            }
          }
        }

        plugins.whenPluginAdded { plugin ->
          println('Checking ' + plugin.class.name)
          if (!added && supportedPlugins.contains(plugin.class.name)) {
            println('Adding to ' + plugin.class.name)
            rootProject.apply plugin: 'com.jaredsburrows.license'
            added = true
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```